# In app billing in android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am getting problem when run sample application of in app billing in device like told me to update market app and i have already the install market app of version 2.3.4 .If any one have hint how to do that please provide solution

Comment: Real Device? Got the Billing Permission? Could you show us the exact logcat error

Comment: it show one dialog  and it say that you can use app but not purchase and yes i have add the billing permission

Comment: Have you changed the code to use a test product id? Like "android.test.purchased" ?

Answer (score 2):

The only other reason I could find in the documentation was

> The synchronous response for a CHECK_BILLING_SUPPORTED request provides a Bundle with a server response code. A RESULT_OK response code indicates that in-app billing is supported; a RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE response code indicates that in-app billing is unavailable because the in-app billing API version you specified is unrecognized or the user is not eligible to make in-app purchases (for example, **the user resides in a country that does not allow in-app billing**). A SERVER_ERROR can also be returned, indicating that there was a problem with the Android Market server.

But I cannot find a list of these countries, you would assume it was the same as those that can buy paid apps:

https://market.android.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=143779

Comment: if possible please tell me step to implement in app billing in app and we can buy paid app in our country so this may not be issue.

Comment: @Vijay fill out your question with some code, or it's just guess work.

Comment: I am also having same problem and i an in Pakistan.

Comment: You could try this tutorial if the android.developer one is a bit complex: http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/simple-inapp-billing-payment-t52060.html